# Python create directory failing

Tags: python, python-3.x, mkdirs

I am using some pretty standard code:

```
 1   if not os.path.exists(args.outputDirectory):
 2       if not os.makedirs(args.outputDirectory, 0o666):
 3           sys.exit('Fatal: output directory "' + args.outputDirectory + '" does not exist and cannot be created')
```

I remove the directory and the check at `1` drops through to `2`. I one-step beyond that and hit the error message at `3`.

However, when I check, the directory was created successfully.

```
drwxrwsr-x 2 userId userGroup  4096 Jun 25 16:07 output/
```

What am I missing??

Comment: Aside: You are probably better off with `if os.path.isdir(...)` rather than `if os.path.exists(...)`. Your code will have unexpected results if intended directory name already exists as a regular file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`os.makedirs` does not indicate whether it succeeded through its return value: it always returns `None`.

`None` is `False`-y, therefore, `not os.makedirs(args.outputDirectory, 0o666)` is always `True`, which triggers your `sys.exit` code path.

---

Fortunately, you don't need any of that. If `os.makedirs` fails, it'll throw an `OSError`.

You should catch the exception, not check the return value:

```
try:
    if not os.path.exists(args.outputDirectory):
        os.makedirs(args.outputDirectory, 0o666):
except OSError:
    sys.exit('Fatal: output directory "' + args.outputDirectory + '" does not exist and cannot be created')
```

If no `OSError` is thrown, that means the directory was successfully created.

Comment: For some reason, passing the access mode as a parameter to `makedirs` did not take effect. The directory was creed, but not with the desired mode.  I added a following `os.chmod(args.outputDirectory, 0o666)` and that worked just fine (Python 3.2).

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to call `os.path.exists()` (or `os.path.isdir()`); `os.makedirs()` has `exist_ok` parameter.

And [as @Thomas Orozco mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31052931/4279), you shouldn't check `os.makedirs()`' return value because `os.makedirs()` indicates errors by raising an exception instead:

```
try:
    os.makedirs(args.output_dir, mode=0o666, exist_ok=True)
except OSError as e:
    sys.exit("Can't create {dir}: {err}".format(dir=output_dir, err=e))
```

Note: Unlike `os.path.exist()`-based solution; it raises an error if the path exists but it is not a directory (or a symlink to a directory).

There could be issues with the `mode` parameter, [see the note for versions of Python before 3.4.1](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.makedirs)